# Laravel subdomain configuration on Centos 7 Apache Virtual Host

Tags: laravel, centos7

I was trying to use laravel subdomain on our centos 7 server. The server was using apache and using vhost, the website is up and running but the problem is that all pages that uses a subdomain is unreachable. After researching, I configure the vhost for the subdomain but still no luck.

This is the original configuration of the vhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/public
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/example/storage/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/example/storage/logs/requests.log combine

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/example/ca_bundle.crt
    <Directory /var/www/html/example>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is the vhost after setting up the subdomain. I also try to use wildcard which also did not work

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/public
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/example/storage/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/example/storage/logs/requests.log combine

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/example/ca_bundle.crt
    <Directory /var/www/html/example>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    Redirect / https://subdomain.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
    #ServerAlias *.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/public
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/example/storage/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/example/storage/logs/requests.log combine

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/example/ca_bundle.crt
    <Directory /var/www/html/example>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also tried to add this subdomain to the list of the hosts which obviously did not work. I also double check the routes files and everything is fine and working locally. Here is my route configuration.

```
Route::middleware(['web', 'auth'])
                ->domain('subdomain.'.config('app.url'))
                ->as('subdomain.')
                ->group(base_path('routes/subdomain.php'));

Route::middleware(['web'])
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

Comment: what is the issue? You can't reach the subdomain? you get always redirected or server the normal domain? Did you restart the service?

Comment: I get this website cant be reach when trying to visit the website.

Comment: Im not sure if this correct but I will try to add it to the dns record of the domain and see what happen.

Comment: Yeah, you must have a CNAME with the subdomain